# android SQLiteConstraintException UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: android, sqlite

how can i solve this exception pleaz help me i added items to a grid view but when i clicked onto the last item at the grid view this exception appear the item deleted correctly but this exception thrown what is the wrong in my code

```
public class MyDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";
// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TABLE_DELETED = "deleted";
// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_dID = "did";
final String KEY_dNAME = "dname";
public MyDataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE"
            + ")";
    String CREATE_DELETED_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DELETED + "("
            + KEY_dID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_dNAME + " TEXT UNIQUE"
            + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DELETED_TABLE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
public void AddnewContact(photos todo)// this method to add new contact
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, todo.getImage());
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
public void AddnewContactToDeletedTable(photos todo)// this method to add new contact
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_dNAME, todo.getImage());
    db.insert(TABLE_DELETED, null, values);
    db.close();
}
public ArrayList<photos> getallcontacts() {
    ArrayList<photos> contactList = new ArrayList<photos>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            photos contact = new photos();
            contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setImage(cursor.getString(1));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
public void deleteContact(photos contact) {
    int id = contact.getId();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID
            + " = " + id, null);
    db.close();
}
```

}

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: contacts.name (code 2067)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:788)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                                                                         at com.example.yasser.ahlysc.MyDataBase.AddnewContact(MyDataBase.java:55)
                                                                         at com.example.yasser.ahlysc.Funny$1.onResponse(Funny.java:59)
                                                                         at com.example.yasser.ahlysc.Funny$1.onResponse(Funny.java:48)
                                                                         at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                                         at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                         at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Answer (score 2):

i think your inserting same value that is why throwing  this error, the alternative solution is you can replace query.

Try below code:

```
public void AddnewContact(photos todo)// this method to add new contact
{
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(KEY_NAME, todo.getImage());
   db.replace(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values); // change this line to your code
   db.close();
}
```

replace query can handle already existing data...